# ConcurrentDictionary performance

Tags: c#, performance, multithreading

i need to improve the performance of ConcurrentDictionary.

for that i created 2 classes for check if the more efficiencies than the original.

```
public class FixedConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    readonly ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue> _dictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>();
    public bool IsEmpty
    {
        get
        {
            return Count == 0;
        }
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return _dictionary.Skip(0).Count();
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<TKey> Keys
    {
        get
        {
            return _dictionary.Select(i => i.Key);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<TValue> Values
    {
        get
        {
            return _dictionary.Select(i => i.Value);
        }
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _dictionary.Clear();
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value)
    {
        return _dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value);
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(TKey key)
    {
        return _dictionary.ContainsKey(key);
    }

    public TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get
        {
            TValue value;
            if (!TryGetValue(key, out value))
            {
                return default(TValue);
            }
            return value;
        }
        set
        {
            _dictionary[key] = value;
        }
    }
}

 public class FixedConcurrentDictionaryToList<TKey, TValue>
{
    readonly ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue> _dictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>();
    public bool IsEmpty
    {
        get
        {
            return Count == 0;
        }
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return _dictionary.Skip(0).ToList().Count();
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<TKey> Keys
    {
        get
        {
            return _dictionary.Select(i => i.Key).ToList();
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<TValue> Values
    {
        get
        {
            return _dictionary.Select(i => i.Value).ToList();
        }
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _dictionary.Clear();
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value)
    {
        return _dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value);
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(TKey key)
    {
        return _dictionary.ContainsKey(key);
    }

    public TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get
        {
            TValue value;
            if (!TryGetValue(key, out value))
            {
                return default(TValue);
            }
            return value;
        }
        set
        {
            _dictionary[key] = value;
        }
    }
}

 public class BenchDictionary : IDisposable
{
    int _length;
    readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim _locker = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
    readonly Dictionary<string, string> _dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    readonly Stopwatch _stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    bool _isStoppedBench = false;
    bool _useStopWatch = false;
    bool _isDisposed = false;
    public BenchDictionary(int length, bool useStopWatch)
    {
        _length = length;
        _useStopWatch = useStopWatch;

        var t1 = new Thread(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _length; i++)
            {
                _locker.EnterWriteLock();
                string str = $"t{i}";
                _dictionary[str] = str;
                _locker.ExitWriteLock();
            }
            if (_useStopWatch)
                _stopwatch.Stop();
            _isStoppedBench = true;
        });
        t1.Name = "t1";
        t1.IsBackground = true;

        var t2 = new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (_isStoppedBench || _isDisposed)
                {
                    if (_useStopWatch)
                        System.Console.WriteLine($"BenchDictionary:: _dictionary.Values.Count: {_dictionary.Values.Count} time elapsed: {_stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds} sec");
                    return;
                }
                _locker.EnterReadLock();
                int count = _dictionary.Values.Count;
                _locker.ExitReadLock();
            }
        });
        t2.Name = "t2";
        t2.IsBackground = true;

        if (_useStopWatch)
            _stopwatch.Start();

        t1.Start();
        t2.Start();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (!_isDisposed)
        {
            _isDisposed = true;
        }
    }
}

public class BenchConcurrentDictionary : IDisposable
{
    int _length;
    readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> _concurrentDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();
    readonly Stopwatch _stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    bool _isStoppedBench = false;
    bool _useStopWatch = false;
    bool _isDisposed = false;

    public BenchConcurrentDictionary(int length, bool useStopWatch)
    {
        _length = length;
        _useStopWatch = useStopWatch;
        var t1 = new Thread(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _length; i++)
            {
                string str = $"t{i}";
                _concurrentDictionary[str] = str;
            }
            if (_useStopWatch)
                _stopwatch.Stop();
            _isStoppedBench = true;
        });
        t1.Name = "t1";
        t1.IsBackground = true;

        var t2 = new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (_isStoppedBench || _isDisposed)
                {
                    if (_useStopWatch)
                        System.Console.WriteLine($"BenchConcurrentDictionary:: _concurrentDictionary.Values.Count: {_concurrentDictionary.Values.Count} time elapsed: {_stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds} sec");
                    return;
                }
                int count = _concurrentDictionary.Values.Count;
            }
        });
        t2.Name = "t2";
        t2.IsBackground = true;

        if (_useStopWatch)
            _stopwatch.Start();

        t1.Start();
        t2.Start();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (!_isDisposed)
        {
            _isDisposed = true;
        }
    }
}

public class BenchFixedConcurrentDictionary : IDisposable
{
    int _length;
    readonly FixedConcurrentDictionary<string, string> _fixedConcurrentDictionary = new FixedConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();
    readonly Stopwatch _stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    bool _isStoppedBench = false;
    bool _useStopWatch = false;
    bool _isDisposed = false;

    public BenchFixedConcurrentDictionary(int length, bool useStopWatch)
    {
        _length = length;
        _useStopWatch = useStopWatch;
        var t1 = new Thread(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _length; i++)
            {
                string str = $"t{i}";
                _fixedConcurrentDictionary[str] = str;
            }
            if (_useStopWatch)
                _stopwatch.Stop();
            _isStoppedBench = true;
        });
        t1.Name = "t1";
        t1.IsBackground = true;

        var t2 = new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (_isStoppedBench || _isDisposed)
                {
                    if (_useStopWatch)
                        System.Console.WriteLine($"BenchFixedConcurrentDictionary:: _fixedConcurrentDictionary.Count: {_fixedConcurrentDictionary.Count} time elapsed: {_stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds} sec");
                    return;
                }
                int count = _fixedConcurrentDictionary.Count;
            }
        });
        t2.Name = "t2";
        t2.IsBackground = true;

        if (_useStopWatch)
            _stopwatch.Start();

        t1.Start();
        t2.Start();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (!_isDisposed)
        {
            _isDisposed = true;
        }
    }
}

 public class BenchFixedConcurrentDictionaryToList : IDisposable
{
    int _length;
    readonly FixedConcurrentDictionaryToList<string, string> _fixedConcurrentDictionaryToList = new FixedConcurrentDictionaryToList<string, string>();
    readonly Stopwatch _stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    bool _isStoppedBench = false;
    bool _useStopWatch = false;
    bool _isDisposed = false;

    public BenchFixedConcurrentDictionaryToList(int length, bool useStopWatch)
    {
        _length = length;
        _useStopWatch = useStopWatch;
        var t1 = new Thread(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _length; i++)
            {
                string str = $"t{i}";
                _fixedConcurrentDictionaryToList[str] = str;
            }
            if (_useStopWatch)
                _stopwatch.Stop();
            _isStoppedBench = true;
        });
        t1.Name = "t1";
        t1.IsBackground = true;

        var t2 = new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (_isStoppedBench || _isDisposed)
                {
                    if (_useStopWatch)
                        System.Console.WriteLine($"BenchFixedConcurrentDictionaryToList:: _fixedConcurrentDictionaryToList.Count: {_fixedConcurrentDictionaryToList.Count} time elapsed: {_stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds} sec");
                    return;
                }
                int count = _fixedConcurrentDictionaryToList.Count;
            }
        });
        t2.Name = "t2";
        t2.IsBackground = true;

        if (_useStopWatch)
            _stopwatch.Start();

        t1.Start();
        t2.Start();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (!_isDisposed)
        {
            _isDisposed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Than i perform bench marking:

```
[MemoryDiagnoser]
[KeepBenchmarkFiles]
[MinColumn, MaxColumn, MedianColumn]
[Config(typeof(Config))]
public class TestDictionary
{
    private class Config : ManualConfig
    {
        public Config()
        {
            Add(
                Job.VeryLongRun
                    .With(BenchmarkDotNet.Environments.Platform.AnyCpu)
                    .WithLaunchCount(1)
                    .WithTargetCount(1)
                    .WithWarmupCount(0)
                    );
        }
    }


    [Params(10000000)]
    public int Length { get; set; }

    [Benchmark(Baseline = true)]
    public void BenchDictionary()
    {
        using (new BenchDictionary(Length, false)) { }
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void BenchConcurrentDictionary()
    {
        using (new BenchConcurrentDictionary(Length, false)) { }
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void BenchFixedConcurrentDictionary()
    {
        using (new BenchFixedConcurrentDictionary(Length, false)) { }
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public void BenchFixedConcurrentDictionaryToList()
    {
        using (new BenchFixedConcurrentDictionaryToList(Length, false)) { }
    }
}
```

The results:
[image]

I will be glad for getting a code review for this implementation.
Thanks.

Comment: What's the reason for the `Skip(0)`?

Comment: few operations in the ConcurrentDictionary cause to acquire all the locks at once: Count, Keys, Values.. so for prevent that i use linq that will attempt to use the count property with it is available..

Comment: OK now I see the point. You're trying to avoid locks by returning an enumerator instead of an array. What happens if I call `fixedDictionary.Keys.ToList()` while another thread is adding an item? Won't you (sometimes) get a "collection was modified" exception? Seems like this is making the dictionary less thread-safe.